# python: generic function call from one instance to another

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a method which calls another method in another instance. I do not know which combination of args and kwargs i get.

So i wrote the following method. But that looks not very elegant and not very pythonic to me.

Is there a better way to implement this?

```
def __call_generic_remote_function(self, rfunc_name, rargs=None, rkwargs=None):
    try:
        lfunc_name = getattr(self.inst_to_wrap, rfunc_name)
    except AttributeError:
        return f"Method {rfunc_name} is not existing!"

    if rargs is None and rkwargs is None:
        result = lfunc_name()
    elif rargs is not None and rkwargs is not None:
        result = lfunc_name(*rargs, **rkwargs)
    elif rargs is None:
        result = lfunc_name(**rkwargs)
    else:
        result = lfunc_name(*rargs)
    return result
```

Comment: You dont need to check if `args`, or `kwargs` contain anything. Python can handle if they are empty. So just do: `return lfunc_name(*args, **kwargs)`. I also don't understand what your are using getattr for. Why not just pass the method itself?

Comment: I use getattr because I do know the name of the method i have to call only at runtime

Comment: Can't the method be passed at runtime? I mean you pass the name  which implies the method can be passed as well. Regardless remove the if statements  and it will look better.

Comment: I want this to communicate between two processes. So the name can be passed but not the method.

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably off topic as it is more opinion based but I would write it something like the following. Can also be a standalone function.

```py
def call_generic_remote_function(object_instance, func_name, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        func_to_call = getattr(object_instance, func_name)
    except AttributeError:
        return f"Method {func_name} does not exist!"
    return func_to_call(*args, **kwargs)
```

Tested Via:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self, a, b, k):
        print(a, b, k)
    def bar2(self):
        print("Called")

f = Foo()
call_generic_remote_function(f, 'bar', 1, 2, k=3)
call_generic_remote_function(f, 'bar2')
print(call_generic_remote_function(f, 'bar3'))
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
Called
Method bar3 does not exist!
```